# Linux CLI: Extract variable number of lines from text file based on search

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface

I have what I thought was a simple problem. I have a mysqldump file occupying several GBs, and I want to create a script that will extract just the lines of the text pertaining to one table (variable passed to the script) and save those to a new file.

The section I want to extract always starts with:

```
-- Table structure for table `myTable`
```

And always ends with:

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Where the table name and the number of lines I want afterward are variable. I'm able to find the start of the section with:

```
START=$(grep -n "Table structure for table \`$2\`" "$1" | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')
```

Where `$1` is the file to search and `$2` is the table name. This works just fine, but then I'm stuck.  I know I can extract the lines with sed once I have the ending line number, but finding that ending line number is the tricky part.

I need to find the line number of the first occurrence of `UNLOCK TABLES;` after my `$START` line number, and I'm lost on how to do that.

For more detail, here's an example of one section of text I would want to extract:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `myTable`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myTable`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `column1` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `column2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`column1`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `myTable`
--

LOCK TABLES `myTable` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `myTable` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES ('test11', 'test12'),('test21', 'test22');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `myTable` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed`; you don't need to worry about explicit line numbers; you can just select the range using regexes for both the first and last line.

```
firstLine="-- Table structure for table \`$2\`"
secondLine="UNLOCK TABLES;"

sed -n "/$firstLine/,/$secondLine/p" "$1"
```

The `-n` limits `sed` to printing only those lines that match the desired range.

Comment: So this will find the first occurrence of `$secondLine` after `$firstLine`?